# Draggable issue with fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar and trying to drag an event from one slot to another, as well as trying to modify the end time of an event, and nothing seems to work. jQueryUI is loaded, fullcalendar has loaded correctly otherwise I wouldn't have a fullcalendar view, and the data shows up in the calendar.

**Note: this is spark laravel.**

view:

```
@extends('spark::layouts.app')

@section('content')
...

<div class="container-fluid>
    <div id="calendar"></div> 
</div>
...

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a.fc-draggable').draggable();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-07-12',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            events: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            disableDragging: false,
            disableResizing: false,
            eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
                // console.log('event:', event);
                // console.log('js-event:', jsEvent);
                // console.log('ui:', ui);
                // console.log('view:', view);
            },
            eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
                // console.log('event:', event);
                // console.log('js-event:', jsEvent);
                // console.log('ui:', ui);
                // console.log('view:', view);
            },
            eventReceive: function(event) {
               alert('eventReceive fired.'); 
            },
            drop: function(date) {
                console.log('drop fired.');
            },
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotDuration: '00:30:00',
            slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
            displayEventEnd: true,
            minTime: '00:05:00',
            maxTime: '24:00:00'
        });

    });

</script>
```

controller function:

```
public function week()
{
    $filters_boolean = 'ON';
    $data = array (
        array(
            'name' => 'Joe Swanson',
            'start' => '2016-07-10T08:30:00',
            'end' => '2016-07-10T11:30:00',
            'account_name' => 'Joe Swanson',
            'phone' => '(604) 555-1234',
            'email' => 'admin@a.com',
            'workers' => 2,
            'created_on' => '2016-07-02T07:00:00',
            'last_activity_on' => '2016-07-02T07:00:00'
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Peter Griffin',
            'start' => '2016-07-11T08:30:00',
            'end' => '2016-07-11T11:30:00',
            'account_name' => 'Joe Swanson',
            'phone' => '(604) 555-1235',
            'email' => 'admin@b.com',
            'workers' => 2,
            'created_on' => '2016-07-02T08:00:00',
            'last_activity_on' => '2016-07-02T08:00:00'
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Peter Griffin',
            'start' => '2016-07-12T09:30:00',
            'end' => '2016-07-12T14:30:00',
            'account_name' => 'Joe Swanson',
            'phone' => '(604) 555-1235',
            'email' => 'admin@b.com',
            'workers' => 2,
            'created_on' => '2016-07-02T08:00:00',
            'last_activity_on' => '2016-07-02T08:00:00'
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Glen Quagmire',
            'start' => '2016-07-10T14:30:00',
            'end' => '2016-07-10T17:30:00',
            'account_name' => 'Quahog Air',
            'phone' => '(604) 555-1236',
            'workers' => 2,
            'email' => 'giggity@quahog-air.com',
            'created_on' => '2016-07-02T09:00:00',
            'last_activity_on' => '2016-07-03T13:00:00'
        ),            
        array (
            'name' => 'Glen Quagmire',
            'start' => '2016-07-15T08:30:00',
            'end' => '2016-07-15T11:30:00',
            'account_name' => 'Quahog Air',
            'phone' => '(604) 555-1236',
            'workers' => 2,
            'email' => 'giggity@quahog-air.com',
            'created_on' => '2016-07-02T09:00:00',
            'last_activity_on' => '2016-07-03T13:00:00'
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Glen Quagmire',
            'start' => '2016-07-11T14:30:00',
            'end' => '2016-07-11T17:30:00',
            'account_name' => 'Quahog Air',
            'phone' => '(604) 555-1236',
            'workers' => 2,
            'email' => 'giggity@quahog-air.com',
            'created_on' => '2016-07-02T09:00:00',
            'last_activity_on' => '2016-07-03T13:00:00'
        ),
    );

    return view('calendar-week', ['data' => $data, 'filters_boolean' => $filters_boolean]);
}
```

Comment: Do your console.log()s get fired on drop and drag start? Also, are you using the latest version of fullcalendar and tried another browser? I had a weird bug when version 2.6 wouldn't work for dragging but only in Chrome, it was fine even in IE.

Comment: Latest version of fullcalendar yes, 2.8.0. The console.log()'s don't fire on drop, but they do fire on dragStart and dragStop. The same issue exists in Safari. The event will go transparent as soon as I begin dragging, and re-appear when I release the click.

Comment: Your code seems to work for drag and drop: http://jsfiddle.net/4vqg6sw4/

Comment: I'm really confused and now I'm not sure what the issue could be :/

Comment: Something else in your page is stealing the events? Try making only a bare page, with just the fullcalendar code and nothing else.

Comment: Just tried that now, and no difference besides my bootstrap not being present :P

Comment: try logging all javascript events and look whether their defaultPrevented property is true

Comment: No, no preventDefault()'s fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out - silly, really. It was both: the order I was loading my resources (even though it gave no error as a clue), and the fact I was using jQuery and jQueryUI.